# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView

Tags: android

I am receiving this issue for Google Pixel 2 X O.S. 8.0 Oreo. Its working on other mobile devices but not only on Pixel.

===========================================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg_img">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relayBottom"
        android:background="#1AFFFFFF">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gvShowHomeBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/PX_77.00"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relayBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_bottom_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/rg_footer_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

===========================================================================

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.recruit.genie/com.recruit.genie.Home_Screen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at com.recruit.genie.fragments.Home_Fragment_New.onCreateView(Home_Fragment_New.java:64)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2435)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:610)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
```

Comment: Share your layout.xml file also. 
`Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView` There seems to have problem in it

Comment: PLease shate your xml file code.

Comment: Please download xml file from this url https://d.pr/FREE/3RjfiF